# Showing the Cantor function is not Lipschitz.

Tags: analysis

This is one I am having a lot of difficulty with.  I'm not sure how to show that the Cantor function (or 'Devil's Staircase) is *not* Lipschitz.

Comment: Maybe you meant _isn't_ Lipschitz?

Comment: You are correct.  I need to fix that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** For every nonnegative integer $n$, find some points $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n|=1/3^n$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=1/2^n$. Conclude.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

I guess I may be misunderstanding what Lipschitz means.  In my mind I like to think of a function having the Lipschitz property as saying that the secants are bounded by a positive M.

Comment: Precisely. The hint indicates that the slope of the secant between $x_n$ and $y_n$ is pretty large, when $n$ is large...

Comment: So would this be where you are going:

$$\frac{|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|}{|x_n-x_y|} \leq \frac{3^n}{2^n}$$.

I guess I'm still not sure what there is that $\leq$.  In my mind, isn't is exactly equal to $\frac{3^n}{2^n}$.

Comment: Yes, equal. $ $

Comment: I noticed that my previous comment made marginal sense.  What I meant to say is: why is it $\leq$ and not $=$?  My gut feeling is to claim this $\leq$, but I don't have a defense for it.

Comment: If you found $x_n$ and $y_n$, you can see that this is $=$. If you did not, I do not understand this conversation. (Note that $\leqslant$ may hold for functions as regular as one wants, for example constant.)