# Is an everywhere differentiable function locally Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If we have a differentiable function $ f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $, does it have to be locally Lipschitz? It's obviously true for continuously differentiable functions, but what happens without that assumption?

Comment: What about stuff like $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to another page, about Cantor function, which is differentiable but not locally Lipschitz. This function is not even weakly differentiable.

[Showing the Cantor function is not Lipschitz.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206108/showing-the-cantor-function-is-not-lipschitz)

Comment: The Cantor function is only a.e. differentiable, so this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: In fact it is a simpler problem. It is hard to find a everywhere differentiable function that is no-where loc Lipschitz continuous. It suffices to get a point x in the domain, that f is not locally Lipschitz near x. You can just take the example on this page.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303695/if-f-is-differentiable-at-a-point-x-is-f-also-necessary-lipshitz-continuo/303717#303717